# Sitecore Form __RequestVerificationToken cookie missing

Tags: configuration, upgrade

I'm working on a Sitecore 10.1.0 upgrade and getting this issue where the __RequestVerificationToken cookie is not in the request.  I think I had the same issue in 9.1.1 but don't recall the solution.  I checked that the rendering and parents aren't cacheable.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.  In web.config  had to change sameSite from None to Lax and requireSsl to False.  My CD sites are not SSL. CM site is SSL so it didn't require the change.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I had the same issue. I had some automated tests and they were failing in our new environment because it was connecting over http:// instead of https://.